# Delete animation of a certain bone for a number of frames Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have an animation of a Mecanim. I wonder how I can delete the animation of only the right-hand for the next couple of frames once I press a certain key in the LateUpdate() function

```
void LateUpdate () 
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.D)) 
        {
            //delete the next lets say 100 frames of only the right-hand
        }
    }
```

If anyone could please advise how this can be done?

Comment: They have a component for that already. In the Biped section where you can control the "Weight" <- Key word for what you need. To be affected. For example You would set the "Weight" : How the particular parts is affected. to 0%. Then the that particular part will not be rendered with the animation. You can also put it in 50% so it will only do the half of the animation and so on. I will send you the link later when I got home.

Comment: @Aizen Thanks for your comment. I want to delete frames of a certain bone, so that interpolation happens in the gap between the before/after the gap. As people suggested to me here that deleting the frames will solve my issue found here http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/102252/frame-interpolation-unity3d

Comment: err. this is a hacky way to do it. And it is not symmetrical. What kind of animation are you using? You said Humanoid so I am guessing Mecanim?

Comment: Great, but I am wondering why you're having a problem losing frames in Mecanim, as Mecanim already have a great control over the Animation, specially Combining Animation that is set to a limb. Have you covered the Full Mecanim Component Tutorial already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment is getting Bigger So I will paste it in here.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xx21y9eJq1U

In this video try to check the 44:51 ish or something. That is what you need. Then Control it with a script when to activate it.

It is a `Masking`. You can mask the animation and so on. You will get the idea when you watch this.

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for, what you sent is adding two layers of different animations. But what I'm looking for is deleting some frames of specific limb in the current animation. So that I can do what I want found here http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/102252/frame-interpolation-unity3d

Comment: On your comment link. The Code is running on Update() which will interfere with the Mecanim. You're able to do it, but it like I said, it is a hacky way. Now if you insist to use this, all you have to do is set the frame = to what you want. Then. on the If else Statement. You don't even have to determine if it is a odd or even number. Just do animation["Walk"].weight = 0.0f; and then another `if` frame is = to something then. animation["Walk"].weight = 1.0f;

Comment: but this will pause the whole animation, right? not the right arm only? And will this pause the animation or interpolates the frames where the weight was set to 0?

Comment: Well No, you can control which frames you are going to stop. Just get the Component of which specific parts you want to stop. The animation Weight is just an example. If you want to over ride the frame, you can always use a very simple logic like. if(frame == 10) then make it 100 so it will skip 90 frame. If you want you can use IEnumerable yielding to pause it and wait for frame to pass by and re execute it.